# How to copy a file from app bundle to the Documents folder with Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

How can I copy a file from the app bundle (read only) to the Documents folder (read-write) using the [Cordova file API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)? Is it possible without using [an additional plugin](https://github.com/peacemoon/cordova-plugin-copyfile)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. Lets think the file is located `www/en_US.json` so when you refer to it, the path used should be `en_US.json`. The destination on the other hand is `cordova.file.documentsDirectory`, specified by the File plugin. So now as you know the paths, what you need to do is to copy the file with File plugin. Here is example which is totally non-tested but should give you the main idea:

```
function copyFileToDocuments(fileToBeCopied) {
    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.copyTo(cordova.file.documentsDirectory);
    }
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.getDirectory(), function(dirEntry) {
            dirEntry.getFile(fileToBeCopied, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry.bind(this),     this.errorHandler);
        }.bind(this));
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess.bind(this), this.errorHandler);
}
```